# Powershell - Exception untraceable

Tags: powershell

This PS 3.0 code was working just fine but suddenly is throwing an exception. I don't understand which method is this referring to.

```
param($mailboxName = "A@b.com",
$smtpServerName = "a.NET",
$emailFrom = "c@d.com",
$emailTo = "e@f.com"
)
Clear-Host 
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned 
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.0\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"

try 
{
  $Exchange2007SP1 = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2007_SP1
  $Exchange2010    = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2010
  $Exchange2010SP1 = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2010_SP1
  $Exchange2010SP2 = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2010_SP2
  $Exchange2013    = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2013
  $Exchange2013SP1 = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2013_SP1

  $exchangeService = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService -ArgumentList $Exchange2010SP2
  $exchangeService.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
  $exchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl($mailboxName)

 $inboxFolderName = New-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId ([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox,$MailboxName)
  $inboxFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($exchangeService,$inboxFolderName)
  $Sfha = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo ([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessageSchema]::HasAttachments, $true)
  $sfCollection = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+SearchFilterCollection    ([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.LogicalOperator]::And);

  $ItemView = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(10)

$downloadDir = "D:\Files"   
  $Results = $inboxFolder.FindItems($sfha,$ItemView)
  $today = Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy"
  #$Results
  cd $downloadDir
  mkdir $today

  foreach ($Res in $Results.Items)
  {
    $Res
    $Res.Load()
    $fiFile = new-object System.IO.FileStream(($downloadDir + “\” + $today + "\" + $attach.Name.ToString()),        [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)

    foreach ($attach in $Res.Attachments)
    {
        $attach.Load()        
        $fiFile.Write($attach.Content, 0, $attach.Content.Length)
    write-host "Downloaded Attachment : " + (($downloadDir + “\” + $attach.Name.ToString()))
    }
    $fiFile.Close()     
    $Res.isread = $true
    $Res.Update([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConflictResolutionMode]::AlwaysOverwrite)
 }

}catch
{
      echo $_.Exception | format-list -Force  
}
```

The error is:

```
ErrorRecord                 : You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
StackTrace                  :    at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
                                 at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
                                 at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                                 at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                                 at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
WasThrownFromThrowStatement : False
Message                     : You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
Data                        : {System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrameInfo}
InnerException              : 
TargetSite                  : Void CheckActionPreference(System.Management.Automation.Language.FunctionContext, System.Exception)
HelpLink                    : 
Source                      : System.Management.Automation
HResult                     : -2146233087
```

Comment: The reason you can't see what method call it's referring to is that you've stripped out useful information by doing `$_.Exception | format-list -Force`. To see the original ErrorRecord, inspect `$Error[0]` or change the `catch` block to just `throw`

Comment: Thanks Matt. I was using the attachment outside the for loop. Now all's good. :)

Comment: Cool, post an answer! ([it's perfectly alright to post and accept answers to your own question if you managed to solve it on your own](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)) :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, why not post your answer as an answer, so others on   SO do not have to spend time looking at questions that show as unanswered, but are answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using $fiFile outside the for loop while using the attachment ($attach). Moved the declaration of $fiFile inside and it worked fine. All as I put echo $Error[0] inside the catch block.